# How to stop auto update of NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I am using Node SASS and Node js in my project. Whenever I build (using Yarn ) my project my Nodejs automatically gets updated to latest version of NodeJS, (which is not supported by Node SASS) , Hence after sometime my builds fails and application stops working.

Whenever I uninstall and install Nodejs version 9 . Project starts working again.

Comment: NodeJS doesn't have any kind of update support, at all, and certainly no auto-update support.  You'd have to manually install a new version.  You may be using NVM (node version manager), which lets you install multiple versions of node.js side-by-side; if you are, perhaps your build script is automatically updating it?  If your project has a ".nvmrc" file, make sure the file is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response.  However I checked my project doesn't has nvmrc,  Also I tried checking the NodeJS configuration, I found  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc  file.  Can I specify anything via Nodejs Setting. Or I have to install NVM  and then specify the Node JS version.

Comment: You can do that (install NVM); I recommend it for any serious node development.  That won't solve your problem though, as I think you might need to do some more digging. You say you "build with yarn", but yarn is not a build tool.  For someone to help you, you should probably add your exact build command (including the implementation, if it's a script), as well as the output of `node -v` before and after a build that "updates" node.

Comment: @ElliotNelson u should make it an answer. u will get points and thanks <3

Comment: I stopped using `node-sass` for this reason. Use `sass` instead. It is 100% compatible with `node-sass`, is officially supported by the Sass project (`node-sass` is maintained by an external developer) and is pure javascript (written in Dart) so has no compatibility issues with any version of Node (`node-sass` is a C library so must be recompiled for each version of Node)

Comment: I mentioned it in my comment above but it's worth repeating. `sass` is the official version of Sass. `node-sass` is not the official version of Sass

Answer (score -1):

Try running the command `nvm list`, to see what version is configured as your "default":

```bash
$ nvm list
->     v16.18.1
       v18.12.1
         system
default -> v18.12.1
```

Try changing the default version via the `nvm install --default <VERSION>` command:

```bash
$ nvm install --default v16.18.1
v16.18.1 is already installed.
Now using node v16.18.1 (npm v8.19.2)
default -> v16.18.1
```